# Elixir httpserver : priv_dir returns something in _build directory, thus I can't send static files that are in source directory

Tags: elixir, webserver

I'm starting Elixir and I'm currently working on a basic web server / API.
I'm only using `plug_cowboy` for now, since I'm focusing on learning the basics.

The server is using `plug :match` and `plug :dispatch` to answer to various `GET` requests.
In one of those answers, I'm trying to send HTML files using the `send_file` function.

My problem being that the server cannot find the files because it doesn't exists where the app searches that file.

HTML file location: `lib/httpserver/priv/index.html`
Searched path: `_build/dev/lib/httpserver/priv/index.html`

There is the code in the Router:

```
defmodule Httpserver.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  forward("/static", to: Httpserver.Static)

  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/" do
    priv_dir = :code.priv_dir(:httpserver)
    index_path = Path.join([priv_dir, "index.html"])
    send_file(conn, 200, index_path)
  end

  get "/:name" do
    send_resp(conn, 200, "Welcome, #{name} !")
  end

  match _ do
    send_resp(conn, 404, "Not found...")
  end
end
```

I have tried:

- looking at ERLang's documentation
- looking at various elixir forum posts
- looking at some older stack overflow posts

All I could find was about the `start_permanent` and `build_embedded` options in `mix.exs`'s `project` function, and did not solver my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`:code.priv_dir/1`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#priv_dir-1) is a helper which knows nothing about your actual code, it just grabs the path where the application **runs** and concatenates it with `"priv"`. After all, in production one does not even have a source folder.

You should either copy the folder manually or use `File.cwd/0` instead.

Comment: I knew that `:code.priv_dir/1` was a "dumb" function, but I thought the `build_embedded` option should've simlinked the priv folder into the `_build` directory if I gave it the good value.

Anyways, the function code now works using `File.cwd/0`, thanks to your answer.

Also it seemed really clunky to me to copy the priv folder in the right directory manually, I feel like not automating this make it very prone to forgetting and thus not working properly.

Comment: @VictorFaure Elixir is a programming language, not a web framework, so it makes sense the compiler only produces code it compiles by default. In Phoenix there is [`mix phx.digest`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Digest.html) to handle this.